# Customizing horizontal scrollbar generated by overflow:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

javascript/html experts. Can anyone tell me how to customize the look of a horizontal scrollbar that appears when the content of a div overflows horizontally? Thank you.

Comment: I ended up using jScrollPane, which took some work, since I'm using the web2py framework. After including the necessary js/css files, it was necessary to disable the overflow-x:auto rule of the overflowing div - in other words, "overflow-x" had to be set to "none" for it to work properly. Not sure about putting it into production, as it's a bit laggy, and even after some modification, the look isn't a great improvement over the default scrollbar. May end up looking at more options. Thanks, everybody!

Answer (score 0):

I know at least one script, which makes custom scrollbar:
http://www.dyn-web.com/code/scroll/demos.php#hz

it's not free, but I think, you can see how it is made, and try to make it by yourself, or if you like it - you can buy script and support the author.

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin specifically for vertical scrollbars. This can easily be converted to horizontal which I plan on doing soon. This is cross-browser compatible, and works back through at least ie8 But here's a link to my plugin on gitHub:

[scrollThis.js](http://bjoshuanoah.github.com/scrollThis.js/)

If you're up to the challenge, feel free to fork it, and when you've made it work, submit a pull request. :)